# Question about a Bernoulli's integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

[image]

This is taken from bernoulli's book *HYDRODYNAMICS* chapter X, p.258.

**My question is about the integration. Can it be correct or there is an error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the terms of your equation, you have
$$(P+p)vdv=\left(P+p-\frac{ap}{a-x}\right)dx$$
Now, we integrate both sides: the first one between $0$ and $v$ (where we tolerate an abuse of notation naming the variable of integration and the limit the same) and the second between $0$ and $x$ (with another abuse of notation). Then, 
$$\int_0^v(P+p)vdv=\int_0^x\left(P+p-\frac{ap}{a-x}\right)dx=\int_0^x (P+p)dx-\int_0^x\left(\frac{ap}{a-x}\right)dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left.(P+p)v^2\right|_0^v=\left.(P+p)x\right|_0^x-(-1)\left. ap\log(a-x)\right|_0^x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(P+p)v^2=(P+p)x+ap[\log(a-x)-\log(a)]=(P+p)x+ap\log\left(\frac{a-x}{a}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(P+p)v^2=(P+p)x-ap\log\left(\frac{a}{a-x}\right)$$
Then, is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's isolate the variables, shall we:

$(P+p) v dv = (P + p - \frac{ap}{a-x}) dx$

Integrating each side, we get the said result, if the constant of integration is zero, you can find it easily because $(u,v)=(0,0)$ (zero speed) when you replace in the equation.

Edit:

It actually isn't equal because there is an extra $a$ on the top of the fraction that I didn't notice. However, if fits $(u,x) = (0,0)$.

So when you integrate, you get $(P+p) \frac{v^2}{2} =  (P+p)x - ap ln(\frac{1}{a-x}) + K$.

If you replace with $(u,x) = (0,0)$, you get $ 0 = 0 + ap ln(a) + K $ which leads to $K = - apln(a)$. With log properties, you find the said formula.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ln(a-x) instead of ln(a/a-x)?

Comment: @VaggelisKyrilas : That is correct, I didn't notice it. I'll edit my answer